# how to import csv file which contain large set of data and have a column which has some null values

Tags: mysql

mysql is removing those rows which contains null values but I want those.
like i have a table

```
create table users
(
    
    user_id int Not null primary key,
    created_at datetime not null,
    company_id int not null,
    language varchar(20) not null,
    activated_at datetime,
    state varchar(20) not null
);
```

**activated_at** is the only column which contains null values.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDdz.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDdz.png)

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOw60.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOw60.png)

Comment: Provide the sample of CSV file rows as a text (available for copying) - pictures are not useful. PS. I do not see NULLs, I see non-specified values (which can be empty string in CSV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully  import your CSV file follow below steps:

First be careful on your date format on the csv file because the `MySQL DATETIME` is in  `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
> parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
> hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
> '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are
> converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or
> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), if the SQL mode permits this conversion.

Copy the data from your `excel` and paste to `notepad++`.
Your data should look like below in the `notepad++`:

```
user_id;created_at;company_id;language;activated_at;state
0;2021-01-01 10:11:05;15415;ger;2021-01-01 10:11:05;active
1;2021-01-01 10:11:05;15416;ita;;pending
2;2021-01-01 10:11:05;15417;english;2021-01-01 10:11:05;pending
3;2021-01-01 10:11:05;15418;ger;;active
```

Then save it to a .csv file and copy to your mysql path (usually it is `/var/lib/mysql` or `/var/lib/mysql-files/`) location.

Then run `LOAD DATA INFILE` into your `MySQL` command line.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/users_tst.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE users_tst 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(user_id,created_at,company_id,language,activated_at,state);
```

And your data should look like:
[image]

Your `activated_at` empty data are in `0000-00-00 00:00:00` format, if you want null you should change table description and instead of leavit empty in your csv file fill it with `NULL`